# Parameter of a macro that does not work and size of the labels with Metapost

Tags: metapost

The idea is to reproduce the image as faithfully as possible. Two problems :
the parameter s is not taken into account;
the size of the labels is still too small.

[image]

```
      \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
      \usepackage{luatex85}
      \usepackage{luamplib}
      \usepackage{unicode-math}
      \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
      \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
      \begin{document}
      \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
     \begin{mplibcode}

     vardef card(expr a, c, s) = image(
         save rectangle;
         path rectangle;
         rectangle = unitsquare xscaled 2 cm yscaled 4cm;
         draw rectangle rotatedaround((1cm,2cm),a) withcolor c;
         label(btex \Huge s etex ,center rectangle) rotatedaround((1cm,2cm),a) withcolor c;
       )

    enddef;

 beginfig(1)
    pickup pencircle scaled 4;

    color pink;
    pink = (3/4, 1/3, 1/3);

    draw card(-10, 1/4[red, white], A);
    draw card(10 , 1/4[green, white], L) shifted 80 right;
    draw card(-10, 1/4[blue, white], E) shifted 160 right;
    draw card(10, pink, A) shifted 240 right;
 endfig;    

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways, but here's something that works.  For better or worse, I changed a couple of things in your original approach (for an answer closer to what you had originally, see first answer in edit history).

- I don't know if or how labels can be done without passing a string in the macro, so I passed your labels as strings, e.g. "A".
- I took guidance from `plain.mp` and did your labels that way.  This additionally allows you to specify a scale quite easily (`pic1` below).
- Rather than rotating the rectangle and label separately, I drew them together and rotated the result.

[image]

Edit: changed to not require extra packages, see edit history for original with `graphicx`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

    vardef card(expr a, c, s) = image(
         save pic,rectangle;
         picture pic[];
         path rectangle;
         rectangle = unitsquare xscaled 2 cm yscaled 4cm;
         pic1= s infont defaultfont scaled 4;% change your scale here
         pic2=image(
                    draw rectangle;
                    draw pic1 shifted (center rectangle-center pic1);
                    );
         draw pic2 rotatedaround((1cm,2cm),a) withcolor c;
       )
    enddef;

 beginfig(1)
    pickup pencircle scaled 4;

    color pink;
    pink = (3/4, 1/3, 1/3);

    draw card(-10, 1/4[red, white], "A");
    draw card(10 , 1/4[green, white], "L") shifted 80 right;
    draw card(-10, 1/4[blue, white], "E") shifted 160 right;
    draw card(10, pink, "A") shifted 240 right;
 endfig;    

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and also for the clear explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another go...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Rounded MT Bold}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef card(expr rotation, shade, letter) = image(
    path rectangle; rectangle = unitsquare shifted (-1/2, -1/2) xscaled 56 yscaled 91 ; 
    unfill rectangle;
    draw rectangle withpen pencircle scaled 4.2;
    undraw rectangle withpen pencircle scaled 3 withcolor 1/2[shade, background];
    label(textext(letter) scaled 6, origin) withcolor shade;
    currentpicture := currentpicture rotated rotation;
) enddef;

beginfig(1);
    draw card(normaldeviate + 10, 1/2 red, "A");
    draw card(normaldeviate - 10, 1/2 green, "L") shifted 80 right;
    draw card(normaldeviate + 10, 1/4[blue, white], "E") shifted 160 right;
    draw card(normaldeviate - 10, 1/2[red, blue], "A") shifted 240 right;
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

## Notes

- the rotation is easier if you shift `unitsquare` so that it is centred on the origin
- `draw` + `undraw` with a thinner pen is a useful trick to get rounded corners
- You can scale the `picture` returned from `textext`
- A little extra random rotation can improve this sort of display

Comment: Thanks for this other solution ; always very good ideas explained with great clarity.